# Getting error in PSNR calculation using Matlab

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I want to find out PSNR and SNR values of two images A and B of same dimension in Matlab.I used the following code

```
[peaksnr, snr] = psnr(A,B)
```

and getting an error

```
Undefined function 'psnr' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.
```

Then I converted both the images into double as follows

```
A = double(A);
B = double(B);
```

and again PSNR is calculated.Now I'm getting an error

```
Undefined function 'psnr' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

Why this is happening?Please help me to troubleshoot the error.

Comment: How are you initializing A and B?  Please show all of the code prior to [peaksnr, snr] = psnr(A,B)

Comment: simply reading the images

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question asks about a MATLAB error that is more dealing with data types and use of MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

**Why this is happening?**

The answer is quite simple and the error message exactly tells you what is wrong: Apparently you do not have the function `psnr()` available on your system.

This might have many reasons. Most probably:

- You are missing a Matlab toolbox that provides this function
- You are missing a Matlab script that provides this function

  - If you have the script, then Matlab does not know about it. Check your Matlab path settings